# What is NVIDIA flipping?

Tags: nvidia

I don't have much graphics knowledge at all. I'm a server programmer, not a games programmer.

I came across the term `NVIDIA flipping` and wanted to get a summary understanding of what it is. The articles I find either:

- render no understanding, but are commentary about games and game-play, and whether flickering and tearing is improved or worsened
- are too low level, talking about "buffer swaps" and similar hyper-technical details

What is a mid-range summary or definition of what "flipping" is?

Comment: Bing's own summary answers this pretty clearly. https://www.bing.com/search?q=nvidia+flipping references this article which clearly states what NVidia flipping is: https://safemode.org/nvidia-flipping/

Comment: @music2myear  No it doesn't.  I don't see an actual definition anywhere in that article.

Comment: From the web search: "Nvidia flipping is a technique used to reduce latency by flipping the rendering process between the CPU and GPU1"

Comment: Note: It appears the Bing search was viewing an older version of that page. The page was updated in March, removing the section Bing had cached.

Comment: this may be more accessible: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/display/flipping . as close as I can tell, video cards output a frame-buffer by drawing its contents to the screen. while that is going on, additional frames are being rendered by the hardware so that new frames are continuously available. you have two options to place those new frames into the output buffer; you can either write them to a backend buffer, and the copy frames from the backend to the frontend, or you can build the backend buffer, and when its time, swap the two buffers as is.

Comment: @music2myear  Thank you. Apologies I missed that.

Comment: @FrankThomas  Perfect. Thank you.